# Get the floor and ceiling of a room

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

How can I get the current floor and the current ceiling of a room with the Revit API? I`m using the 2012 version.

I`ve tried:

```
 segments = el.GetBoundarySegments(new SpatialElementBoundaryOptions());
```

and:

```
var cs = el.ClosedShell;
```

and even this:

```
SpatialElementGeometryCalculator calculator = 
  new SpatialElementGeometryCalculator(doc);

SpatialElementGeometryResults results = 
  calculator.CalculateSpatialElementGeometry(el);

Solid roomSolid = results.GetGeometry(); 

foreach (Face face in roomSolid.Faces)  
{
    // Subface Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no simple way to do this. You need to loop on faces, like in your third sample and compare the normal direction against Z vector (with `XYZ.IsAlmostEqualTo`).